# PHPUnit doesn't recognize file_exists()

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I've set up a project with unit test files in NetBeans. I set bootstrap to `C:\www\foo\_tests\TestAutoload.php` and put simple autoload method to this file:

```
function __autoload( $class_name ) {
    // series of ifs
    if ( ... ) {
        $file_name = ...
    }

    if ( file_exists ( $file_name ) ) {
        require_once( $file_name );
    } else {
        echo "autoload error";
    }
}
```

All of my tests fail on autoload this way. They always output just "autoload error". If I don't check if `file_exists` and just use `require_once( $file )` no matter what's in `$file`, it works perfectly.

Anyone encountered anything like this before? It's not something I couldn't resolve by simply not checking whether file exists or not, but I'm interested why it does this and if I can cheat it somehow.

Comment: is the $file_name a full path or relative path?

Comment: I thought it was absolute path, but disturbance in force made it relative instead :) Please, see my comment to pinkgothic's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try using **file_exists()** on absolute filenames if they aren't, already, e.g. `file_exists($file_name)` might be `file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../myclasses/' . $file_name)`, since (as per amphetamachine's answer), **[file_exists()](http://php.net/file_exists)** does not use the include_path setting of PHP.

Comment: You've pointed me the right direction. The problem was that I used $_SERVER[ "DOCUMENT_ROOT" ] in autoload, which was an empty string as PHPUnit is running through CGI, therefore resulting into relative path being passed into file_exists. Now I'm parsing my own "document root" and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

From the [PHP Manual page for `file_exists`](http://www.php.net/file_exists):

> Be aware: If you pass a relative path to file_exists, it will return false unless the path happens to be relative to the "current PHP dir" (see chdir() ).

Answer (score 1):

give the absolute path in the file_exits function, it might have the file path not correct in that file_exits function what u have worte